# elementary embeddings, $V$ vs. $L$

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

What is possible from these choices, there is an (nontrivial) elementary embedding $$j:V\to L$$
or
There is an elementary embedding $$j:L\to V$$

and second part of my Q. is to what is this consistent condition equivalent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Neither option is possible**.

The key point is that "being $L$" is first-order expressible: since $L\models$ [$\mathsf{V=L}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_constructibility), if there is an elementary embedding *either* way between $V$ and $L$ we must have $V\models\mathsf{V=L}$ and so $V=L$. But by the [Kunen inconsistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kunen%27s_inconsistency_theorem), there is no elementary embedding from $V$ to itself.

---

A couple comments:

- Re: $V$, $L$, and $\mathsf{V=L}$ above, this is not a typo: I reserve the "mathsf" font for axioms and theories, and normal italicized Roman letters for objects.
- Invoking Kunen here is overkill: you can prove more elementarily from $\mathsf{ZFC+V=L}$ that there is no (nontrivial) elementary embedding $L\rightarrow L$ *(while on the other hand, the existence of an elementary embedding $L\rightarrow L$ follows from a measurable cardinal or indeed much less)*. However, I think bringing Kunen into the picture is helpful here since it presents a more unavoidable theme.
- The Kunen inconsistency requires choice (to the best of our current knowledge), and so one might hope to avoid the argument above if we merely assume $\mathsf{ZF}$. But remember that in fact $\mathsf{ZF}\vdash (L\models \mathsf{AC+V=L})$, so this doesn't help.